# Android: Application is running in Android device but not working in Emulator

Tags: android

I am working in android. I designed an application. Whenever i run this application in android device then it works fine. but when i run this application in android then it crashes.

these are statements in CatLog:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(TabHost.java:295)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:661)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1819)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me to find out the reason for this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please post some code around TabHost.java:295

Comment: Sir TabHost.java is not my class, its JAVA class at android.widget.TabHost.

Comment: Provide the information about emulator's API Level.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by my own efforts. This is related to Memory capacity of emulator. I created new AVD which has large CD card capacity and Heap size so it working properly.

Thank you so much who tried to help me.